# Localhost:5000 keeps on loading when using Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, localhost

I tried setting up a website for the first time but the localhost:5000 page wont load.

I followed the steps of https://pythonhow.com/html-templates-in-flask/ the code they suggest is

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return "Hey there!"
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

the output that python gives me is:

> - Serving Flask app "**main**" (lazy loading)
>
>   - Environment: production
>       WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
>       Use a production WSGI server instead.
>   - Debug mode: on
>   - Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   - Restarting with stat
>       An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>       SystemExit: 1
>       /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>       warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Then when I try to load the localhost:5000 page it just keeps on loading but never 'reaches' the site. I've looked all over for people with the same problem but couldnt find something that helped me.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check if the port is open with command line?   Run in command line 'netstat -noa' and see if there is a line goes like this : 0.0.0.0:5000 and the state is Listening.

If not i think you should try a tutorial on how to open ports in a windows PC:
https://windowsreport.com/open-firewall-ports/


you can also look for use of a external cmd command called tcping and how to use it.

http://www.tucows.com/preview/516900/TCPing

Comment: @JimErginbash not 100% sure what you mean since im new to website building.

But if i re-run the last line of code: "app.run(debug=True) " then i get a whole lot of error messages whereof the last line states that: "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use"

Does this mean that the port is closed? And how could I solve this?

Comment: Try with some manual configured ports like: `app.run(host='localhost', port='5002',debug=False)`

Comment: It means that you already having a site running on this port.
It feels like maybe you ran the server before, and somehow even if you stopped it your computer still behaves like it runs.
Either change the port you run on or just restart the computer so that will make sure no process of 'server hosting' will be caught by port 5000

Comment: @viktorw. This means your port is already listening. May be some other instance of your website is running  in the same port.

Comment: can you please let us know how are you running your application.? What is the command line?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for all the quick feedback it is resolved by either: 
1. restarting my copmuter as suggested by @JimErginbash 
or
2. substituting the command line `app.run(debug=True)` for the line `app.run(host='localhost', port='5002',debug=False)` as suggested by @VidyaSekar
or by both ofcourse :)
Thanks a lot!